# Extract specific number from a textboxes

Tags: vb.net

How can I extract from this Textbox, for example what is in parentheses (9,2,8)

```
Textbox1.Text =

1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20 (9)
5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 (2)
2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20 (8)
```

And display in another textbox, `Textbox2.Text = 9,2,8`

Comment: Will the number always be in parentheses or did you only use them to highlight the number you are after?

Comment: the number will always be in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way of doing it.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s1 = "1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20 (9)
5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 (2)
2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20 (8)"

        Dim re = New Regex("\(([^)]*)\)")
        Dim things = re.Matches(s1)

        For Each m As Match In things
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 9
> 2
> 8

For this *[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, I think a railroad diagram helps to explain what it does:

[image]

From https://regexper.com/#%5C%28%28%5B%5E%29%5D*%29%5C%29

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result using a simple [While loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/while-end-while-statement)

```
    <TestMethod()>
Public Sub ExtractNumbersInParentheses()
    Dim inputString As String = "1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20 (9)
5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 (2)
2, 3, 5, 6, 11, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20 (8)"

    Dim finalResult As String = String.Empty

    Dim startingPosition As Integer = inputString.IndexOf("(", 0)
    While (startingPosition > 0)

        If (finalResult.Length > 0) Then finalResult += ", "

        Dim extractedText = inputString.Substring(startingPosition + 1, 1)

        finalResult += extractedText

        startingPosition = inputString.IndexOf("(", startingPosition + 1)
    End While

    Debug.Print(finalResult)
End Sub
```

The key part is the [`.IndexOf` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) and each time you query the inputString you move the starting position to be beyond the current position otherwhise you will see the same parenthesis

After I ran this test, the output was:

> 9, 2, 8